# selenium Python how to check if a table column is sorted alphabetically

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have page with a table of 5 columns and some rows.  When i click on the header of column 1 (index ID is 1) it sorts the rows in alphabetical order.
I would like to verify has the column sorted the rows in ABC order.
I do not know how to do this part.

I have written the Selenium Python code to click the header and I have code which can loop through the table.  In the for loop I would like to check has the column sorted the data in ABC order.
I need some help how to check if the text in each row is in ABC order.

My code snippet for the for loop iterating over the table is:

```
def is_column_sorted(self): # Is the columns sorted in ABC order when the header was clicked 
    try:
        table_id = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'data_configuration_data_previews_ct_fields_body')))
        rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
        for row in rows:
            # Get the columns
            col_name = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1]  # This is the Configuration Name column
            col_type = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[3]  # This is the Type column
            col_rows = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[4]  # This is the Rows column
            print "col_name.text = "
            print col_name.text
            print col_type.text
            print col_rows.text
            if (col_name.text == "data1"):
                return True
        return False
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
        print "Element not found "
        print e
        self.save_screenshot("data_previews_page_column_sort")
        return False
```

My TestCase code snippet which clicks the header is:

```
def test_sort_data_preview(self): # On teh Data preview view page click col 1 (Configuration) to sort it
    print "*** Test sort_data_preview ***"
    tool_bar = ToolbarPage(self.driver)
    data_previews_page = tool_bar.clickDataPreviews()
    data_previews_page.select_a_data_preview(Globals.datapreview_crm_name)
    data_previews_view_page =     data_previews_page.click_view_link(Globals.datapreview_crm_name)
    data_previews_view_page.click_column_header_to_sort()
    data_previews_view_page.is_column_sorted()
```

E.g. The data in Col1 could be:

```
Lademo_CRM_Data_Preview
Test Character Code 
Escr data preview
Selenium CRM Data Preview 
etc
```

After I click the header of Col1 the webpage will be sorted alphabetically.
How do i check if it has sorted it correctly?

Thanks,
Riaz

Comment: Before the column is sorted I could iterate over the rows and store the value of column 1 into a List.  Sort the list in ABC order.  I then click the column to sort it and then iterate over the rows and compare the values with the values in the List.  If it matches then the column has sorted in alphabetical order.  Test passed.  What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I truly believe that testing sorting on the front-end via automated functional tests is not the best practice. If you have access to the code, test the sorting algorithm there instead.

If you still want to to do it, i suggest reading all the column data into a list before clicking the sort and then sorting the list using pythons sorted() function. I wrote some pseudocode below, hopefully it works out for you.

```
 unsortedlist = self.driver.find_elements(By.Locator, row_element)
 self.driver.find_elements(By.Locator, sort).click()
 sortedTable = self.driver.find_elements(By.Locator, row_element)
 sortedList = sorted(unsortedList, key=str.lower)
 for item in sortedTable:
     assert sortedTable[i] == sortedList[i]
```